# Swift lazy initialization can't conform to the protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2

I declared several UI components in a protocol.

```
protocol SomeViewContainer {
    var aView: ACustomizedView
    ...
}

class TestViewController: SomeViewContainer {
    var aView: ACustomizedView!

}
```

The above code won't pass because the compiler doesn't think `TestViewController` conforms to the protocol.

The `aView` will be initialized after the data fetched from the remote, so I can't just remove the `!` .
In addition, I would prefer to lazy initialzation like the following for some other properties declared in the protocol.

```
lazy var aView: UIView! = {

    }()
```

Still Failed to compile.
Are there any ideas on how to conform a protocol with lazy initialization?

Answer (score 4):

So two issues, one a property with type `ACustomizedView!` is not the same as a property with `ACustomizedView` which is why it doesn't conform

Secondly, you should be able to use lazy.
Is that your actual code?

lazy initialization uses a self executing closure, so it'll run the closure code automatically when called and supply the property with what the closure RETURNS

the fact you have nothing inside the closure will cause it to break..

you need to actually return a view from inside the closure

```
lazy var aView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    // configure view
    return view
}()
```

Comment: Well, that's my mistakes. Thank you. But how to initialize it in somewhere like `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: right so the entire concept of lazy means its initialized whenever you use it for the first time. AKA don't worry about initializing it, just use it where you normally would and if it hasn't been initialized yet it'll do that for you at that point.